# Add a json object to req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express

I have learnt about sending form values via req.body. How can I append a new value/json to it? For eg. if the form contains only one or two input fields and submit, which sends a post request, how do i append a json object to the req.body recieved by express server?

I am designing a rest api with express for angular to access. I need to send json to express for post requests. It is a shopping cart(as a json object of products and rates) which i have to send to the backend to place an order(store in mongo).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the content-type to application/json. You can build your JSON object from the form data:

```
var data = {
  id: form-model-id,
  name: form-model-name
}
```

For more information see [ng-http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

```
$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/something/cool', data, {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
}).then(function (response) {
  callback(null, response.data);
}, function (response) {
  if (response.status === 0) {
    throw { message: 'api_timeout' };
  } else {
    if (response.status === 409) {
      throw { message: 'api_login_failed' };
    } else {
      callback(response.status, response.data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems cool. So i access it via express using req.body.data, right?